# A lattice with Monster group symmetries

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, sporadic-groups

The book *Mathematical Evolutions* contains the following excerpt:

> A last, famous, example is the following. It is known that in the space
> of one hundred and ninety six thousand eight hundred and eighty three
> dimensions there is a wonderful lattice whose symmetry group has order
>
> 808 017 424 794 512 875 886 459 904 961 710 757 005 754 368 000 000 000
>
> = $2^{46} \cdot 3^{20} \cdot 5^9 \cdot 11^2 \cdot 13^3 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 41 \cdot 47 \cdot 59 \cdot 71$
>
> Of course, no-one has really seen this lattice: we know that it exists,
> but an explicit construction is lacking. Nevertheless, one can construct
> the symmetry group of the lattice, the so-called *monster group* $M$ of
> R. Griess and B. Fischer.

The existence of such a lattice is not immediate: for example, the simple group $A_5$ has a faithful three-dimensional representation, but there is no lattice in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an (orientation-preserving) point symmetry group isomorphic to $A_5$.

However, a remark in a paper by Conway reveals the existence of a (probably unimodular) integral lattice in 196884 dimensions which is closed under the Griess algebra multiplication:

> Norton has shown that the lattice $L$ spanned by vectors of the form $1, t, t \ast t'$, where $t$ and $t'$ are transposition vectors, is closed under the algebra multiplication and integral with respect to the doubled inner product $2(u, v)$. The dual quotient $L^{\star} / L$ is cyclic of order some power of 4, and we believe that in fact $L$ is unimodular. The vectors $t, u, v, w$ of Table 3 all lie in $L$.

Now, if we take the intersection of the 196884-dimensional lattice $L$ with the orthogonal complement of the fixed axis $1$, we obtain a 196883-dimensional integral lattice $L'$ with Gram determinant $|L'| = 3|L|$. This is an explicit construction of a lattice with the properties alluded to in the *Mathematical Evolutions* excerpt.

The orientation-preserving point symmetry group of this lattice $L'$ is isomorphic to the Monster group $M$, and the full point symmetry group is isomorphic to the direct product $M \times C_2$ (since the ambient dimension is odd, so the negated identity matrix $-I$ is an orientation-reversing symmetry which commutes with everything).

I'd like to understand this 'wonderful lattice' $L'$ in greater detail. So, now for a pair of concrete questions:

- **Question 1**: what are the shortest nonzero vectors in the lattice $L'$?

The shortest vectors I can find are those of the form $x := t - t'$ (where $t$ and $t'$ are the axes of two type-2A involutions whose product is also a type-2A involution), which each have doubled inner product $2(x, x) = 448$. The number of such vectors is 2639459181687194563957260000000, one for each arc (oriented edge) in the [Monster graph](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/the-monster-graph-and-mckays-observation). If these are indeed the shortest vectors, then the sphere packing corresponding to this lattice would be moderately dense (but not record-breakingly so, and well below Minkowski's lower bound on lattice density).

- **Question 2**: does the set of shortest nonzero vectors generate the lattice?

The fact that the Monster graph is connected implies that any vector of the form $t - t'$ (where $t, t'$ are *any* pair of axes of type-2A involutions) is generated by the aforementioned norm-448 vectors. But I'm not immediately convinced that these generate the lattice $L'$, because Norton's lattice $L$ was described as being generated by vectors of the form $1, t, t \ast t'$, rather than just vectors of the form $1, t$.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I have uploaded a python package (with optimized C subroutines)  that can do some calulations in the moster and also generate random 2A transposition axes $t$. See:

https://github.com/Martin-Seysen/mmgroup